# Is it the code, or is it the OS..?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, nasm

**MY CODE IS**

```
.model small

.data  
arr db 83h, 12h, 0F0h, 0Bh, 89h  
cnt db 05h

.code  
mov ax, @data  
mov ds, ax  
mov si, offset arr  
mov cl, cnt  
sub bl, bl  
sub dl, dl

back:  
mov al, [si]  
and al, 80h  
jz skip  
inc bl  

skip:  
inc dl  
inc si  
dec cl  
jnz back  
mov ah, 4cH  
int 21H  
end
```

**THE ERRORS ARE AS FOLLOWS**

1.asm:1: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
1.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected
1.asm:2: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
1.asm:9: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand

Comment: _"Is it the code, or is it the OS..?"_ I'm curious why you think it could be the OS.

Comment: Your assembly code is in MASM/TASM syntax, that won't work with NASM. You'd have to translate it from MASM to NASM to assemble it or use MASM/TASM or even JWASM to assemble it.

Comment: If you actually end up compilin and linking it, this won't run on Linux(Ubuntu) without a DOS emulator (DOSBox, DOSEMU etc / DOS in a VM etc). If you want to create a Linux program in assembly using NASM  I recommend googling for something like NASM LINUX TUTORIAL Be aware 64-bit programs and 32-bit programs have differences.